# DPM 2010 not updating last backup time on Exchange 2007 CCR system

Tags: exchange-2007, scdpm

We have just installed DPM 2010 and backing up an Exchange 2007 CCR system. All the backups go through fine, but it does not update the last backup time on the database which causes the log files not to be cleared.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been identified with the help of Microsoft. Exchange 2007 SP3 broke the backup of the passive node in a CCR cluster. If you switch the backup to the primary server in the CCR cluster, all log files will be truncated correctly. Microsoft has sent me an Interim update for Exchange 2007 SP3 which fixes this problem.

You can find more information at the following [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvravailabilityandisasterrecovery/thread/2b5de9de-7c7e-4398-8793-8a6c397f2195).

Answer (score 0):

With DPM, there are two types of backups, incremental and Express Full.  The logs will be truncated only when an Express Full backup takes place.  Take a look at [this](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Backing-Up-Exchange-Databases-via-Passive-Node-Exchange-Server-2007-CCR-Cluster.html) article and verify that you have your backup schedule set to take Express Full backups.

Comment: The backup is setup for full express, even when running it manually it still does not truncate the logs.

Comment: @Francois, DPM will use VSS to truncate the logs.  Open a command prompt, type vssadmin list writers (check both nodes).  Verify that the VSS writers (notably the Exchange writer) are in a stable state.  If they aren't, you'll need to reset the writers.  See my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/137126/vss-error-521-when-attempting-backup/137133#137133) for more specifics on troubleshooting VSS.